# NodeJS route redirect page with Angular clicked value

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

Node JS:

```
var toSend = [ 
    {"id":1, "topic":"Topic1", "name": "Name1"},
    {"id":2, "topic":"Topic2", "name": "Name2"}
    ]


app.get('/topics', function(req, res){
    return res.json(toSend);
    });
});


app.get('/newpage/id/:id', function(req, res){
    var theid = req.params.id;
    return res.json(theid);
});
```

In my index.html page i have the following:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="topic in topics">
       <a ng-href="newpage/id={{topic.id}}"> {{topic.name}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
<script src = "myapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myapp.js :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get( "/topics").success(function( data) {
        $scope.topics = data;
    });
});

app.controller("newpageCtrl", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get( "/newpage").success(function( data) {
        $scope.name= data;
    });
});
```

And in the newpage.html :

```
//HTML same to index.html. The body is: 
<body>
    <div ng-controller="newpageCtrl">
        {{name}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Everything works fine until I click on `<li>` in my index.html. I never go to the newpage with the id passed from Angular `ng-href`. What I want to achieve is to show the `li` in the index page and when i click on any link, take me to the newpage with the id clicked. I cannot seem to pass the value from node. If I use express and define a view, i can pass the value using `<%= data.name %>`. But I want to use Angular's template.

How do i pass the clicked value in Angular page to NodeJS and redirect the page to another Angular page with the correct value?

Thanks.

Comment: Routing works different in angular. Go through the angular routing concepts.

Comment: Kalyan, thanks. But can I use angular routing when im using Nodejs also?

Comment: Of course. In your case, you are using Node Js for your API purpose. Your front end is Angular JS. http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/09/28/angularjs-tutorial-for-beginners-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb/

Comment: I tried using ng-route and also have followed that tutorial. Its  static page used in the tutorial and i want to change between pages. I want to open a page when a link is clicked in AngularJS and pass it to NodeJS and pass a json value to a Angular Page.

Comment: Been trying this for more than 6 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have plunker code which uses angular-ui-router explained.

May be you can use it as a base and build your sample on top of that.'

https://plnkr.co/edit/OfFwSA?p=info

```
(function(){

  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('plunker')
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider)
  {
      $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
              url: '/', 
            templateUrl: 'home.html'      
            })
      .state('sports', {
      url: '/sports', 
      templateUrl: 'sports.html'      
      })    
        .state('sports.football', {
        url: '/football', 
        templateUrl: 'football.html'      
        })
        .state('sports.weightlifting', {
        url: '/weightlifting', 
        templateUrl: 'weightlifting.html'      
        })
        .state('sports.swimming', {
        url: '/swimming', 
        templateUrl: 'swimming.html'      
        })
      .state('country', {
      url: '/country', 
      templateUrl: 'country.html'      
      });

  }])
  .controller('testCtrl',function(){

  });

})();
```

on your Html:

```
<body >
    <ul> 
       <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="sports">Sports</a></li>
       <li><a ui-sref="country">Country</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the awesome built. Still scratching my head on how to integrate nodejs and passing variable between the pages.

Comment: You have to use $http promise for calling you node js api.

Comment: Im still unable to understand how to do it. Can you show me a working example please?

Comment: I created a restful api and able to create a CURD app. I can get/post/put/delete the values now. My only question is, how do i show the value of a single entry in a new page?